# how to open a qtp(.usr) file in read/write mode using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am able to open QTP Application using vb script but when i try to open the file, it is opening in read only mode and when i run the script it don't read data from the excel sheet it should have been reading from.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim qtpAppObj,qtpTest

'Create the QTP Application object
Set qtpAppObj = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") 

'Open the test in read-only mode
qtpAppObj.Open c:\test, True  

'set run settings for the test
Set qtpTest = qtpAppObj.Test
```

I am using the code above

So i want to read an excel file and i think it can't be read because of the read-only mode.

Comment: I don think opening test in read-only mode is the issue. when you say it doesnt read data from excel sheet you mean data table or external excel sheet?

Comment: @user5612655
yes you get it right.
i want to read data from an external excel sheet.
and earlier i thought opening test in read-only mode is the issue but it is not.
how can i read external excel sheet?

Comment: So you mean you are able to read data from an external sheet when you run normally but not when you run using QTP AOM? Can we please see the code of how you actually open excel and read the data please because I guess the question is mainly not able to read the data using excel rather than it is not working when using QTP AOM

Comment: @user5612655 the issue is actually while using QTP AOM. while running the test normally it is working

Comment: @AkashS. - not able to clearly understand your question, but you can check your driver script, the code which actually reads the data from excel - check for the object of excel in your script

Comment: @Pranav The code which reads data from excel works fine when I run the  test manually in QTP . But when i use vb script to run the test it doesn't read the excel sheet.

Comment: @AkashS. Yes, show the code that reads the excel file - the code which is in your AOM script not the code you use in your action

Answer (score 0):

This `True` is for opening the test in read only mode.

```
qtpAppObj.Open c:\test, True
```

Change it to false and run

```
qtpAppObj.Open c:\test, false
```

Comment: Thank you Vinoth it is working
But i am still not able to read the excel sheet
After running the test, the control just passes through the driver action, idealy it should pass to other actions also but not happening in this case

Answer (score 0):

Can you Please show the code which is reading the excel file.
I think you maybe reading data from Datatable.
So thats why it is reading from inside the test but not able to read with QTP AOM.

Please show the excel reading code.

Comment: Thank you, The issue is been resolved now, i was just unable to read the excel sheet due to wrong path of environment files.